# C#, sorting a jagged array related to other (normal) array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays:

```cs
int[][] array1 = new int[x][];

double[] array2 = new double[x];
```

I want to sort array2, but array1 is related to array2. Their indexes are identical, and by sorting array2 i lose connection to array1.

I know about Array.Sort, but it seems to not work in this case.

Comment: How does `Array.Sort(array2, array1)` not work? Can you [edit] the post with some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: "does not work in this case" is not an explanation of the problem. Please [edit] question to clarify how it does not work for you - in mean time it indeed looks like duplicate suggesting to use `Array.Sort`.